# How to fold nested list items in markdown-mode

Tags: code-folding, markdown-mode, hideshow

I would like to be able to fold nested list items in markdown-mode in the same way that it is possible to do in org-mode, so that, for example, the first sub-item in the following list can be easily hidden.

- List item 1

  - List item 1.1
- List item 2

The result would look something like the following.

- List item 1 ...
- List item 2

And ideally I would like to be able to use the mouse to fold and unfold the relevant blocks of text, and to have a marker displayed in the left margin to indicate that a block can be, or has been, folded.

From what I've read, it looks like the most promising option may be to use hs-minor-mode, which allows the use of the mouse to fold and unfold blocks, along with hideshowvis, which displays indicators in the margin for the blocks that can be folded, or have been folded, by hs-minor-mode. I've tried out a few other ways of doing the folding that work ok---in particular, selective display, origami, and yafolding---but, as far as I could see, none of them allowed for the use of the mouse to fold and unfold blocks.

I tried to set this up using hs-minor-mode but couldn't get it to work. I think I needed to define a 'forward-sexp' function, or something, but this is beyond my current capabilities.

Has anyone set up markdown-mode to fold nested list items like this? Does anyone have any advice on how I could get it working?

Answer (score 4):

`markdown-mode` uses parts of `outline-mode` for folding. So, IMHO it is most natural to implement the folding of items also with the help of `outline-mode`.

The most obvious way would be:

1. to include beside `markdown-regex-header` also `markdown-regex-list` in `outline-regexp`
2. to replace the function `markdown-outline-level` as value of variable `outline-level` by some other function which also assigns levels to matched lists.

Pityingly, step 2 of this strategy does not work since `markdown-mode` uses `outline-level` in other contexts. So, an advice is needed for `markdown-outline-level`.

Setting the `mouse-face` and `keymap` text properties on heading markers and list items [is quite standard](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html).

[`md-outline-list.el`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/md-outline-list) is an example implementation of a package that can fold items in Markdown files. You can toggle the folding by mouse-clicks on the bullets or the heading markers.

Marking the foldable regions on the fringe is not (yet) implemented.